# onRest function not behaving propperly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, react-spring

My issue is that I am following a tutorial and for some reason the countdown animation for the roullete is not loading propperly. It decreseases from 10 , but it stops at 9.94 for some reason

I have atached the github link below since my code is too long
https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/micriteo/RoulleteGame/tree/main/front-end

Image of my countdown issue
[image]

Comment: include this link in your description [gitpod](https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/micriteo/RoulleteGame/tree/main/front-end)

Comment: First, you [can't just paste a link to your page/code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) Post the relevant code to your question. Second, only one issue per question.